# How to change image using arrow keys using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this gallery. I need to change the image when the user will press the arrow keys after the modal popup. left arrow key to change the image in the left and the right arrow key for right. I'm pretty new to javascript so if you can help me it would be great.
Please see the code snippet in full page.

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";

  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";

  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 58%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  margin-left: 300px;
  max-width: 779px;
  min-width: 779px;
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.close {
  position: relative;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
  left: 584px;
  top: 90px;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: -149px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  left: -10%;
}

.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: -149px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  left: 600px;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <td>
        <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x900" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
      </td>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <td>
        <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x910" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
      </td>
    </div>
</tr>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>

    <div class="mySlides">

      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x900" style="width: 98%;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 109px;">
      <p id="caption" style="padding-bottom: 7px;font-size: 17px;">Annual function</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">

      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/1600x910" style="width: 98%;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 109px;">
      <p id="caption" style="padding-bottom: 7px;font-size: 17px;">Annual function</p>
    </div>
    <a class="prev" id="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

Comment: `</div></tr>`  what? No `<table>`? No `<td>` ? inline `onclick`? Why? Also, don't use anchor elements if you actually want a `<button>`.

Comment: I post the short code

Comment: If you ask me, `<p>` is *short code*. Not some broken unnecessary markup. `<div>` cannot be a direct child of `<tr>` - learn about the [HTML Table element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) and its markup.

Comment: `id="caption"` multiple times? ID should be unique. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: `.mySlides`? That's *one single* slide - but that's a "naming things" thing. Inline `style` ... avoid that. Use stylesheets.

Comment: You should group your images so that you can have multiple slideshows groups of slide images and not worry about conflicting code.

Comment: It's also not the best idea to load a huge image just to preview it as a thumbnail... It would be best to use different size images, one for the view and the other higher-res for the slideshow. Something like `<img src="thumbnail_1.jpg" data-gallery="high_res_1.jpg" data-gallery-group="gal-1">`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        document.getElementById("prev1").click()
    } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        document.getElementById("next1").click()
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.